# Is there a way to validate SSH public key in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, ssh, ssh-keys, public-key

I want to validate a user submitted public key in php. I want something equivalent to `ssh-keygen -lf` command.

I've tried [violuke/rsa-ssh-key-fingerprint](https://github.com/violuke/rsa-ssh-key-fingerprint), but unlike `ssh-keygen -lf`, it does not say if public key is valid or not. It returns a hash regardless of key being valid or not.
How can I validate public key in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try load your key using [`PublicKeyLoader::load`](https://phpseclib.com/docs/publickeys) from [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/).

If it succeeds, the key should be valid.